# "[geom-type or SRID not allowed]" only after first call to `AddGeometryColumn`

Tags: spatialite

I'm getting an error that "[geom-type or SRID not allowed]" for a geometry column, but I'm confident that the value I'm inserting is valid for the type and SR.  I noticed that if I drop the table and recreate it again with the same value SQL, I no longer get the error.  For example, in the query below, I get the error with the second DROP/CREATE/AddGeometryColumn commented out, but not if I uncomment it.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (Value double);
SELECT AddGeometryColumn('test', 'SHAPE', 32615, 'LINESTRING');
--DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
--CREATE TABLE test (Value double);
--SELECT AddGeometryColumn('test', 'SHAPE', 32615, 'LINESTRING');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (46.71864700317383, GeomFromText('LINESTRING (701268.032645698 3675362.29477,701268.032645698 3675364.29728502,701265.122816664 3675368.30231507,701264.28479163 3675368.86824025,701261.045560283 3675372.30734512,701260.272152777 3675372.78885241,701256.259513924 3675375.65843502,701255.162166084 3675376.31237516,701252.246875071 3675377.76809262,701248.234236219 3675378.84164383,701244.221597366 3675378.58692897,701240.208958513 3675376.3929278,701240.119712612 3675376.31237516,701236.663233482 3675372.30734512,701236.19631966 3675371.17638664,701234.972864821 3675368.30231507,701234.36868546 3675364.29728502,701234.36868546 3675362.29477)'))
```

https://www.screencast.com/t/1aP4rXEdhap

Is this expected behavior?

[image: spatialite_gui version info]

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue .. The second `AddGeometryColumn` call doesn't add the validation triggers to the table, which is why it appears to work.  The real fix is to include the SRID as the second parameter to `GeomFromText`.